# Was the Agora chat room always a stream of videos and articles that one user finds personally interesting, or is this a more recent characteristic?

Tags: discussion, chat

In the last 12 days one user has posted 16 videos and over 50 article links that I suppose they think everyone should know about.

I would like to know how folks see the following:

1. Is this pretty much what Agora has always been like, or is it a recent occurence
2. Is this pretty much what Agora *is for?*
3. Any thoughts on whether this enhances Agora's utility or interferes with it?
4. Would perhaps a separate room for "user's news feed" be a better place for this activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this pretty much what Agora has always been like, or is it a recent occurence?

- [December 4, 2012](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2012/12/04): Just introductions
- By about [June 2013](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2013/6/3) through until [August 8, 2022](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2016/8/22): mostly question feeds, with some occasional discussion
- On [August 8, 2016](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2016/8/22), the question feed stopped being posted in the Agora
- On [September 27, 2016](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2016/9/27), there was live discussion of a presidential debate
- Since then, there was mostly discussion and the meta feed, but the balance has ebbed and flowed. This was the state until about [April 12, 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2019/4/12), when a user, *Martin Sleziak* started posting news or opinion links alongside a short comment for context or reaction.
- The room had to be [unfrozen several times in May 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2019/5/13).
- Martin's link-posting continued: [May 18](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2019/5/18), [May 24](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2019/5/24)
- *you* started being active around then ([May 25, 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2019/5/25))
- From then on, Martin's links were a dominant feature of the chat. On many days (e.g. [June 1, 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2019/6/1)), Martin posted multiple links.
- This continued until about [September 5, 2022](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2022/9/5).
- On [September 26, 2022](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2022/9/26), User1865345 (whose practice you are now asking about) started posting links following the norm established by Martin. Martin's posting dropped off.
- [When the chat is quiet, the links dominate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2022/11/3). [When there is a lot of conversation, the links are simply interspersed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6619/2022/11/29).
- That has continued until today.

Answer (score 0):

A counter question is what do you think that it should be for if not for users sharing what they find interesting? What is the stream of links blocking or preventing from happening?

If you look at the chat history not much ever happens in the channel and almost no one uses it. In the end that is a place for people to chat and sharing news links is just another place to chat.

If you want it to be used for other things I would suggest trying to use it for other things. I would also say that sharing links to other questions and answers isn't the purpose of chat and is just something else that it can be used for.